# passing a List of Lists as a parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have a List of Lists of strings and I want to pass it to another method.

I am a little confused about Lists and I don't know how to handle them.

```
public Form(string[] header, List<> data)
```

Is List a data type (or Object)? because the error VS2010 says that its expecting a type.

Comment: Fixed the issue you had about my English grammer. Thanks but you shouldn't downvote because of bad grammer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at `List<T>` as template for building types. It is not actually a type, even though it's known as generic type.

When your program runs, it can't make objects of such types. This is where it gets confusing. They are used to build new types using type parameters. Type parameters are types which you pass to generic type. For example:

1. `List<T>` - generic type
2. `T` portion - type parameter. T can be any type, e.g. `string`
3. if you use generic type (1), and some type as type parameter (2) you create new type: `List<string>`

You have so created new type `List<string>`. For each type parameter C# compiler creates new type. So `List<string>` is completely different from `List<int>`.

It's of course more complicated than that under the hood. Types are actually created by .NET framework at runtime. This allows you to decide which types you want to create while your application is running. C# compiler though, has compile time type checks so it is also aware of this concept and doesn't allow you to simply perform invalid operations on generic types.

Caveat: templates are already existing concept from C++, which you shouldn't confuse with C# generics.

Comment: public Form(string[] header, List<List<string>> data) is the code but Nikola has a better explaination

Answer (score 7):

List<> - is generic data type. You should put type of list's item into the brackets, in your case this is List of strings - `List<string>`.

```
public Form(string[] header, List<List<string>> data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `List<List<string>> data`